# VisualC# 文字列の置換

Tags: c#, 正規表現

テキストボックス２つとボタン１つの簡単なアプリケーションを作っています。
textBox1に入力された文字列をボタンを押すと置換されたtextBox2に表示させるだけです。

textBox1に

```
http://example.com/2244/ha/saitama/jfa4w09f.12.jpg
```

と入力すると

```
<img src="http://example.com/2244/ha/saitama/jfa4w09f.10.jpg">
<img src="http://example.com/2244/ha/saitama/jfa4w09f.13.jpg">
<img src="http://example.com/2244/ha/saitama/jfa4w09f.22.jpg">
<img src="http://example.com/2244/ha/saitama/jfa4w09f.24.jpg">
<img src="http://example.com/2244/ha/saitama/jfa4w09f.30.jpg">
```

と置換されます。
ポイントはここです。
.{10~50までのランダム数字}.jpg
この10~50までの数字はランダムに足されていきます。

文字列の置換方法を教えて下さい。MSDN公式正規表現サイトを見ても難儀でした。

Comment: 目的にマッチする正規表現が分からないときは[オンラインチェッカー](http://regexhero.net/tester/)とかが便利です。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

よう分からんですが...

こういうことですか？
replaceの入力：

> "http://example.com/2244/ha/saitama/jfa4w09f.12.jpg"

replaceの出力：

> "http://example.com/2244/ha/saitama/jfa4w09f.16.jpg"
>   "http://example.com/2244/ha/saitama/jfa4w09f.29.jpg"
>   "http://example.com/2244/ha/saitama/jfa4w09f.45.jpg"
>   "http://example.com/2244/ha/saitama/jfa4w09f.50.jpg"
>   "http://example.com/2244/ha/saitama/jfa4w09f.23.jpg"

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url ="http://example.com/2244/ha/saitama/jfa4w09f.12.jpg";

        var urlList = replace(url);

    }

    static public List<string> replace(string url)
    {
        Regex r = new Regex(@"^(.*\.)\d+(\.jpg)");
        string prefix = r.Replace(url, @"$1");
        string suffix = r.Replace(url, @"$2");

        List<string> urlList = new List<string>();
        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            urlList.Add(prefix + rnd.Next(10, 51).ToString("00") + suffix);
        }

        return urlList;
    }
}
```

Comment: 完成です
private void bt1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            const int THUMBNAIL = 8;
            string url = textBox1.Text;
            Regex r = new Regex(@"^(.*\.)\d+(\.jpg)");
            string prefix = r.Replace(url, @"$1");
            string suffix = r.Replace(url, @"$2");

            List<string> urlList = new List<string>();
            Random rnd = new Random();

            for (var i = 0; i < THUMBNAIL; i++)
            {
                textBox2.AppendText(prefix + rnd.Next(10, 51).ToString("00") + suffix + System.Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }

Answer (score 2):

正規表現にマッチした文字列を置換するには、`Regex.Replace` メソッドを使用します。
例の場合 「ピリオドがあって、１桁以上の数値があって、ピリオドがある。」にマッチさせる正規表現パターンは"`\.\d+\.` ですが、文字列中でエスケープ文字(`\`)を書くために`\\`にして`"\\.\\d+\\."`です。
`Regex pattern = new Regex("\\.\\d+\\.");` で正規表現オブジェクトを作成して
`pattern.Replace(original, number_string)` で指定した文字列でマッチした部分を別の文字列で置き換えます。

---

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class replace_sample {
    public static void Main(){
        string original ="http://example.com/2244/ha/saitama/jfa4w09f.12.jpg";
        int ramdom_number = 25;
        string number_string = "." + ramdom_number + ".";
        Regex pattern = new Regex("\\.\\d+\\.");

        string result = pattern.Replace(original, number_string);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```