# 文字列の部分置換

Tags: c#, .net, 正規表現

文字列の部分置換を行いたいと思うのですが
簡単な方法を教えてください。

例えば

`String data = "かきくけこさしくせそあいくえお";`

最後の"く"を "う" に置換したい。
次は、"く" を "す" に置換したい。

例では、規則性があるように見えますが、実際の
データは、置換する文字列の前後は、規則性がありませんので
正規表現は、使用できません。

以上

Comment: 重複か判断できませんが[VisualC# 文字列の置換](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/8816/visualc-%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%97%E3%81%AE%E7%BD%AE%E6%8F%9B)という非常に似たタイトルのものがあります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

通常、このような条件だとsayuriさんの例のように正規表現で処理するのが常道かと思います。

が、どうしても、System.Text.RegularExpressions名前空間は親の仇で使えない等の理由があるのであれば、お手軽なメソッドは用意されていないと思われるので、String.LastIndexOf()と.Substring()を使ってちまちま切張りするのがおそらく一番ストレートなアプローチになるでしょう。

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var source = "かきくけこさしくせそあいくえお";
    var a1 = ReplaceLastMatch(source, "く", "う");
    var a2 = ReplaceLastMatch(a1, "く", "す");
    Console.WriteLine(a2);
}

private static string ReplaceLastMatch(string str, string target, string alternative)
{
    var pos = str.LastIndexOf(target);
    if (pos >= 0)
        return str.Substring(0, pos) + alternative + str.Substring(pos + target.Length);
    return str;
}
```

Comment: さん 正規表現が適用できると思っていませんでしたので
正規表現以外で簡単な方法が無いかと質問しました。
結果としては、回答して頂いた方法がベストアンサーと
なります。

Answer (score 7):

> 最後の"く"を "う" に置換したい。
>   次は、"く" を "す" に置換したい。

を文字通り実現すれば正規表現でも構わないでしょうか？

```
String data = "かきくけこさしくせそあいくえお";

// 最後の"く"を "う" に置換したい。 => 「く」以降は末尾まで全て「く」以外
data = Regex.Replace(data, "く(?=[^く]+$)", "う");

// 次は、"く" を "す" に置換したい。 => 同上
data = Regex.Replace(data, "く(?=[^く]+$)", "す");

Console.WriteLine(data);
// "かきくけこさしすせそあいうえお"
```

Comment: 勘違いしていました。正規表現でもできるのですね。
勉強になりました。ただ、正規表現以外の方法を探しています。

Comment: @Devai さん、コメントを読み違えていました。質問文の「規則性がありませんので正規表現は、使用できません。」の文意を「正規表現以外の方法を探しています。」と読み取るのは難しく私にはできませんでした。